# Call a controller from a method

Tags: codeigniter, methods, controller

Can we call a controller and parsing any values or data to the controller from a method?
let's say that i have this method,

```
function loader(){
  //some operations to call another controller
}
```

and from that method i want to call a controller named welcome.php wich is located in /application/controller

i'v tried this but it doesn't work

```
function loader(){
   $open = new Welcome();
}
```

it says that `Class Welcome not found`

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

At first You have to include the file

`include('welcome.php');`

Then, create the object.

```
function loader(){
    $open = new welcome();

    //if you want to call a method in an object

    $open->MyWelcomeMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Makesure that your loader controller was `extended` to welcome controller.

Suppose controller welcome,my_controller are two controller and loader function in B then

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
     function my_fun() {}  
}
```

then you can call my_fun() when you are entended from my_controller like

```
class My_Controller extends Welcome {         
      $open = $this->my_fun();
}
```

Comment: i've extended my loader class to welcome controller, it gives me the same error message, `class Welcome not found`

Comment: Try it and tell me if any concern

Comment: i've extended my loader class to welcome controller, it gives me the same error message, class Welcome not found

Comment: @Wildan Muhlis : including the Welcome it also doesn't work. it's still gives the same error message as the result